# WPF simple gallery

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to create a simple gallery that would load images from a folder and then simply display them on the grid with a slider. I've did some research but i just can't make the images to show up - all i get is blank space. Below is what i did so far.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FGOhelper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FGOhelper"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="FGO Little Helper" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="74*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="443*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="257" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="imageItems">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>


    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace FGOhelper{
public partial class MainWindow : Window{
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
        String pathPhoto = @"D:\images\fgotest";
        imageItems.ItemsSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathPhoto, " *.jpg");

    }}}
```

Comment: Take the space out of your search string.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Thanks a lot, that did fix my problem.